# NSDateComponents : Find older than 30 days

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents, date-comparison

Using `NSDateComponents` I want to compare a departure date with now to see whether the departure date is > 30 days.

I use the `NSDateComponents` feature but in debugging it, its always like a really big number when I expect it to be 3 days, or 15 days or whatever.

```
   NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:departureDate toDate:now options:0];

    NSInteger age = [components day]+1;
```

When I try to log the age

`NSLog(@"age (in days) = %lu", (long) age);`

it returns a really long number like `18446744073709551613`

I would like to do an if statement that says;

`if (age > 30)` but am unsure of how to do this when the age being returned is a long number like this.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you log `departureDate` and `now`? I think that `[components day]` should be negative also since I guess that `departureDate` is later than `now`. So your test `> 30` shouldn't trigger correctly.

Comment: `NSLog(@"age")` logs `age`, not the content of the variable named `age`. Please show us the real logging code.

Comment: You are correct, NSLog age doesn't log the age.  I updated issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [NSDate date];
double now = [dateNotFormatted timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%f",now);

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate * dateDepareture =[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"29-06-2015"];
double dateDept = [dateDepareture timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%f",dateDept);
```

Check the doublevalue for 30 days...

**OR**

```
NSDateComponents *components;
NSInteger days;

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2-07-2015"] options:0];
days = [components day];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)days);
```

Change the code to your need check for 30 days...

> NSDayCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0,
>   "Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead") = NSCalendarUnitDay

Comment: Do I need to add `days = ([components day] + 1);`  I did a test against a timestamp that is exactly 30 days ago and it comes up with 29 days not 30

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate* date30 = [NSDate date];
date30 = [date dateByAddingInterval:86400*30]; 

if([departureDate compare:date30] == NSOrderedDescending){
    //Departure > Today + 30d
}    
else
{
    //Departure < Today + 30d
}
```

Is it what you need?